# sql command not properly ended error

Tags: java, sql, sql-update

This is my code to update student attendance.But during execution this method returns SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED ERROR.

```
private void updateAttendance(){
        MyQuery mq=new MyQuery();
        Connection con=mq.getConnection();
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("Select STU_ID FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME='"+cmbName.getSelectedItem()+"'");
            if(rs.next()){
                //System.out.println("getting student name");
                int id=rs.getInt("STU_ID");
                String sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET SUBJECT='"+cmbSub.getSelectedItem()+"',ATTENDANCE='";
                //sql+="ATTENDANCE='"+"";
                if(rdbtnPresent.isSelected())
                    sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"',";
                else
                    sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"',";
                sql+="WHERE STU_ID='"+id+"'";
              st.executeUpdate(sql);
                //cmbName.removeAllItems();
            }

        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you debug the `sql` value and show us what you get? Btw very big sql injection warning. Use parametrized statement. Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quote (`'`) from `ATTENDANCE='";`

Remove comma after `Atdnc[0]` and `Atdnc[1]` because your code puts a comma before `where` clause.

If `stud_id` is a number, then you should not set `id` with a quote (`'`).
Make sure there is a space before `where`.
An example (you can print your sql to see restitution):

```
String sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET SUBJECT='"+cmbSub.getSelectedItem()+"', ATTENDANCE=";
if(rdbtnPresent.isSelected())
   sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"'";
else
   sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"'";
sql+=" WHERE STU_ID="+id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In update statement single quotes are using two times
remove `'` from `ATTENDANCE='";`

try below

```
String sql="UPDATE STUDENT SET SUBJECT='"+cmbSub.getSelectedItem()+"',ATTENDANCE=";
if(rdbtnPresent.isSelected())
   sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"'";
else
   sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"'";
sql+="WHERE STU_ID='"+id+"'";
```

I strongly recomment to use parameterized query to avoid [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: After editting the code getting this error- java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: CREATE TABLE  "STUDENT" 
   ( "STU_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
 "MOBILENO" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(50), 
 "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100), 
 "STREAM" CHAR(50), 
 "SEMESTER" CHAR(50), 
 "DATE_OF_BIRTH" DATE, 
 "CURRENT_DATE" VARCHAR2(50), 
 "SUBJECT" VARCHAR2(200), 
 "ATTENDANCE" VARCHAR2(20), 
  CONSTRAINT "PK_STU_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("STU_ID") ENABLE
   ) ;

Comment: There is an extra comma before `WHERE`. Change `sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"',"; ` to `sql+= "'"+Atdnc[0]+"' ";` ( and `sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"',"; ` to `sql+= "'"+Atdnc[1]+"' ";`) or try Enjy's solution.